# XSLT: Eliminate XML Nodes That Have Qualifying Nodes In Set (XSLT 1.0)

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xslt-1.0

Let's say I have the following XML:

```
<School>
    <Class name="Biology"/>
    <Class name="Math"/>
    <Class name="English"/>
    
    <Student className="Biology" Name="Chris"/>
    <Student className="English" Name="Kevin"/>
    <Student className="Biology" Name="Tania"/>
    <Student className="Math" Name="Kevin"/>
    <Student className="English" Name="Tania"/>
</School>
```

What I would LIKE to do (in XSLT 1.0) is to eliminate the "Student" nodes with the name "Tania" and the Class nodes that they are related to by "className." So something that generates an output like this:

```
<School>
    <Class name="Math"/>
    
    <Student className="Math" Name="Kevin"/>
</School>
```

Is this something that I would do with keys somehow?

Comment: Your example eliminates Chris, presumably because he is part of the Biology group, and Biology has been eliminated because Tania was part of the Biology group. How far would this process go? If Chris also studied Economics, would you drop that class too, and all its students? A clearer spec is needed. (One example does not constitute a specification!)

Answer (score 2):

This XSLT will produce the desired result

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" standalone="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="st" match="Student" use="@Name"/>

    <xsl:template match="Class[@name = key('st', 'Tania')/@className]"/>
    <xsl:template match="Student[@className = key('st', 'Tania')/@className]"/>


    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```